# How does the SendToKindle work?

Tags: web-services, web, kindle-fire, kindle, kindlegen

I'm been research on SendToKindle function, currently I'm using the Chrome SendToKindle Plugin. I want to implement this kind of function by using a web-service.

From what I see, the "SendToKindle" is analyzing the webpage by send the page to the amazon server, and then it will return a new url which will only contain the main article(Without any other elements).

e.g. 
I reading this article:
http://www.nicholascarr.com/?page_id=21
use Chrome SendToKindle: 
I got following new url:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle/reader?article=1392945012941

Dose anyone know how it this been implemented ?
Any help will be highly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does sendtokindle/Reader/Reading View works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901367/how-does-sendtokindle-reader-reading-view-works)

Comment: Not sure if that question been published or not, I received a message said something "rejected"...